# How does Pex work

Tags: pex

At a low level, how does Pex work?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/) videos that explain how Pex works but I'd take a look at [this one](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/briankel/Pex-Automated-Exploratory-Testing-for-NET/) first. A lot of the episodes of [The Verification Corner](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/verificationcorner/) also go over the concepts even if they don't say so explicitly.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for those links. I read somewhere it uses the clr profiling api. I'm trying to find out more about this.

Answer (score 5):

Nikolai Tillmann answered the same question on the Pex forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/pex/thread/71c90936-b3af-4d90-af87-f6ecba797cb7